# Creating 20 different numbers from 1-30 no duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class randomNumbers {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] nums = new int[20];
    Random rn = new Random();
    int temp;

    for(int i=0;i!=20;i++) {
        temp=rn.nextInt(30)+1;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            if(temp==nums[j]) {
                j=0;
                temp = rn.nextInt(30)+1;
            }

        }
        temp = nums[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i!=20; i++) {
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the program. But the output is all zeros. The first loop should run 20 times and generate a random int from 1-30, then the nested loop should test and see if it is in the array.If true then a new temp should be created and j set to 0 to check again. If not, then the nested loop should finish and temp set equal to nums[i]. But like i said my output is all zeros.

Comment: You never assign anything to the nums array items. For example, where do you see `nums[i] = anything`? This isn't a programming question, but rather a basic logic question: if you never put anything into a box, the box remains empty, right?

Comment: `"...and temp set equal to nums[i]"`, and if it does this, all it does is set temp equal to 0. Realize that this does not assign anything to `nums[i]`. To assign something to a variable, that variable has to be on the **left** side of the assignment, and this I think is one of your main misunderstandings. This is a core Java concept, one that you will learn best from java text books and study.

Answer (score 1):

Use collections, dont reinvent the wheel:

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random rnd = new Random();
while (mySet.size() < 20) {
    mySet.add(rnd.nextInt(30) + 1);
}
System.out.println(mySet);
```

---

this will print:

> [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 16, 20, 23, 22, 24, 27, 26, 29, 30]

---

## Update

Another option suggested by @user3745362

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            myList.add(i + 1);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(myList);
        System.out.println(myList.subList(0, 19)); //return a sublist from 0 to 19
```

this will print:

> [15, 17, 24, 29, 3, 18, 22, 5, 13, 8, 19, 11, 10, 27, 12, 26, 20, 30, 16]

Comment: You could also just fill up an ArrayList with consecutive numbers from 1 to 30, shuffle it, and then pull out the first 20 elements.  Either way is fine.